# Autocomplete does not showing the results from controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The autocomplete code written is getting the results from controller and is also showing when used F12 developer network tab with the browser. But the actual returned result is not showed by the textbox, only drop-down with no values are shown.
I'm including the codes of view and controller. Please help me out to solve this.

code of the view page :

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
  <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("hi");
            $("#ValueField").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Customer/AutoretrieveCustomer",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { term: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            var items = $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.FirstName,
                                    value: item.FirstName
                                };
                            });
                            response(items);
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
         });     
        </script>



</head>
<body>

    <div id="CusView">

            <label for="FirstName">Enter Customer First name : </label>
            Enter value : <input type="text"  id="ValueField" />


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

code of the controller :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult AutoretrieveCustomer(string term)
        {
            Banking.BankingDBEntities db = new BankingDBEntities();

            var suggest = from s in db.Customers
                          select s.FirstName;
            var namelist = suggest.Where(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower()));
            return Json(namelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Also I would need the code for getting the id of the user selected item in the textbox.

The following the output pic when the autocomplete is executed

[image: This is output when the code is run autocomplete is firing but the result is not shown in the right manner]

Answer (score 0):

This bit in your controller action:

```
var suggest = from s in db.Customers
                      select s.FirstName;
var namelist = suggest.Where(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower()));
```

Means that your controller action is actually returning an array of strings, not an array of objects like your `success` function is assuming.

You should be able to remove the mapping and just call `response` directly with the array of strings:

```
success: function (data) {
    response(data);
}
```

Or, just:

```
success: response
```